# How to configure range slider for decimal value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following code for range slider. it work for complete values e.g 1 , 100 but not working for decimal value . want want to range it from 0.001.
i tried ,replacing 1 with 0.1 but not working

```
<script>
        $.each($('.slider-input'), function() {
            var $t = $(this),

                    from = $t.data('from'),
                    to = $t.data('to'),

                    $dailyProfit = $($t.data('dailyprofit')),
                    $totalProfit = $($t.data('totalprofit')),

                    $val = $($t.data('valuetag')),

                    perDay = $t.data('perday'),
                    perYear = $t.data('peryear');


            $t.ionRangeSlider({
                input_values_separator: ";",
                prefix: '{{ $basic->symbol }}',
                hide_min_max: true,
                force_edges: true,
                onChange: function(val) {
                    $val.val( '{{ $basic->symbol }}' + val.from);

                    var profit = (val.from * perDay / 100).toFixed(1);
                    profit  = '{{ $basic->symbol }}' + profit.replace('.', '.') ;
                    $dailyProfit.text(profit) ;

                    profit = ( (val.from * perDay / 100)* perYear ).toFixed(1);
                    profit  =  '{{ $basic->symbol }}' + profit.replace('.', '.');
                    $totalProfit.text(profit);

                }
            });
        });
        $('.invest-type__profit--val').on('change', function(e) {

            var slider = $($(this).data('slider')).data("ionRangeSlider");

            slider.update({
                from: $(this).val().replace('{{ $basic->symbol }}', "")
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Which range-slider? what is the script's name?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: $t.ionRangeSlider

Comment: You can edit the step value,
So in your case it would be 

Example on site:
$("#range_30").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 2.34,
    grid: true,
    grid_snap: true
});

Comment: ionRangeSlider works perfectly with decimals. BTW, what is the purpose of your `.replace('.', '.')`?

Answer (score 2):

i just addd .

step: 0.001

and replaced (1) with (8)